# Add image by URL is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, image-upload

We can't paste the URLs provided by newbies into the "Add Image" URL selection because it is gone.

Please add it back.

---

Here's an example: [Can't Find Other Web Pages, Except Index - Where Are They?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53079623/608639) Newbie could not link to images, but the imagur URLs are in the question (click edit to see them).

Here's the new Add Image interface without a place to add images by URL (I don't have the image locally).

[image]

(You might also consider fixing the layout while you are in there twiddling bits).

Comment: MSE duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317578/cant-upload-image-from-url-anymore

Comment: Why would you re-upload those images? They're already on Imgur... Just put a ! in front of the link and they're immediately embedded.

Comment: @Shog - I would not re-upload them. I would dial in the URL so they are displayed. If adding the already uploaded URL causes a re-upload, then I'd say that's another site bug.

Comment: That's how the old uploader worked - adding a URL re-uploaded the image. The *original* image insertion dialog (circa 2008) did just format the link as an image embed, but that's been gone a long, long time.

Comment: @Shog yeah but `if (url.Contains("i.stack.imgur.com")) { DontUploadButInsertLink(url); } else { UploadAndInsertLink(url); }`...

Comment: FYI (as per the MSE duplicate) pasting URLs works in Firefox but doesn't in Chrome. Just Ctrl-V the URL of the image.

Comment: Weren't you also able to paste images you had in the clipboard in the old popup as well?  It doesn't seem like you can do that anymore as well.

Comment: These aren't stack.imgur images, @CodeCaster - they're normal imgur images.

Comment: @Shog9 FWIW I can't see i.imgur.com images at work because Imgur is home to all kinds of NSFW and random stuff. I got my security team to unblock the stack.imgur subdomain specifically by pitching that that subdomain exclusively hosts topical work-related content and that some useful information is shared via screenshots that I might miss out on when trying to find/follow a solution. So... there *is* a legitimate case for re-uploading images that are already hosted at i.imgur.com URLs, albeit an edge one.

Comment: More important than that, @TylerH, is that images on the main imgur domain aren't guaranteed to stay around forever. The images uploaded to stack.imgur.com, however, do have that guarantee

Comment: @Shog9 it's not as simple as adding a `!`. It's more like `[![image][1]][1]` to make it a 'clickable' image since people seem to want to post their entire extra-wide-screen desktop to the point you have to click the image to expand it.

Comment: Well... I guess if you wanna make that right, you'll load the image into an editor & crop or even create a thumbnail then, @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - but either way, that's a lot more work.

Answer (score 5):

This should be working now in both Chrome and Firefox: once the upload dialog is visible, just paste the image URL and you'll be prompted to upload it:

[image: animation of the action described above]

This still isn't entirely *discoverable* - that'll come next, see: [Can't upload image from URL anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317578/cant-upload-image-from-url-anymore/317591#317591)

Also, it doesn't work at all in IE 11.

Comment: _"It doesn't work at all in IE 11"_.. So, no one's going to have any issues then, great!

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I was under the impression that it *was* a feature.

Comment: Jokes aside, uploading (from the filesystem) works fine in IE11 - it's the upload from URL bit that doesn't. Supporting IE11 is becoming a pain; expect more rough edges as it grows more and more out of date.